# Example of a custom deleter method

Tags: python, python-datamodel

I have come across various examples of a custom `getter` or `setter`, but what would be a use case of when a custom `deleter` would be used? So far an example that I have is just something like this:

```
def __delattr__(self, attr):
    print('Deleting attr %s' % attr)
    super().__delattr__(attr)
```

Comment: Can't speak to this definitively, hence why I am not putting in an answer, but perhaps your object has attributes which are set to other objects, and you might need to do some cleanup on those objects for deleting the reference to the variable. (E.g., peacefully terminating some kind of I/O stream or connection before deleting the reference to it.) I am simply speculating, though, as I have never seen a class override the `__delattr__(...)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a standard datamodel hook for customizing what a statement `del obj.attr` will do, instead of (or in addition to) removing the attribute from the instance `__dict__`. So, user code is free to implement whatever they want!

As an example, you could use it as a "soft delete" feature, e.g. to hide an attribute from public access without actually removing the data behind it. Personally, I have used it to invalidate caches when the corresponding get attribute method has a caching layer in front of it.

For a stdlib example, consider the [`Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) class. By default, mock instances will generate child mocks for any attribute access. The public API to "opt-out" of a child mock being auto-generated on a particular name is [implemented via a custom `__delattr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L741-L756).

```
>>> from unittest.mock import Mock  
>>> mock = Mock()   
>>> del mock.attr2  # prevent mock.attr2 from working
>>> mock.attr1  
<Mock name='mock.attr1' id='4414043216'>
>>> mock.attr2
AttributeError: attr2
```